# Create 3D kernels with Pytorch: Is there a simple way for large kernels?

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to test multiple kernels for convolution in 3D space. Here `k` is a 7x7x7 cross kernel, where the voxel in the middle of the kernel equals `1` and all other voxels in the wings equal `-1`. This way of assigning `k` is messy and time-consuming. Any ideas to make it more clear and simple?

```
tensor([[[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

          [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

          [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

          [[ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [-1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

          [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

          [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

          [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with column and row assignments, given `kernel_size`, in your case `7`. 
Keep in mind that the shape of a [`nn.Conv3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html) layer weight is `(out_channels=n_filters, in_channels, kernel_size_depth, kernel_size_height, kernel_size_width)`.

```
>>> n = kernel_size // 2
>>> k = torch.zeros(1,1,*(kernel_size,)*3) # define zero tensor

>>> k[...,n,n,:] = -1 # middle column at middle depth
>>> k[...,n,:,n] = -1 # middle row at middle depth
>>> k[...,n,n] = 1    # middle point at all depths
```